# Is it ok to put html comments outside the <html> tags?

Tags: html

W3c validator didn't ding me on this, but I was curious if anyone else had an opinion on placing html comments outside of the html tags?

```
...
</body>
</html>
<!-- byee -->
```

I have an application and am outputting some data and want it to be the absolute last thing that is done, which unfortunately means I've already attached my last </html>.

Answer (score 18):

I can't see this being a problem - allowable comments are not specified in a DTD (as they're effectively for humans, not computers). Also, the DOM API (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html) explicitly allows many comments directly under the document node (i.e. not the root HTML element, the logical document root), so any conforming browser should allow it.

This is not to say you won't find browsers or tools, especially older ones, that choke. But I'd be surprised if there were many.

Comment: I have not seen any browser complain about this. Just for fun I tested in the ancient Mosaic 2.1.1 (from 1996!!) and even this very old browser didn't complain.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think a comment after the </html> will cause any problems, but I believe that a comment that precedes the DOCTYPE declaration (and therefore before the <html> tag) will kick IE6 into quirks mode.

Comment: This actually affects more than just IE6. lengthy discussion here about why w3 won't make this invalid HTML: http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12072

Answer (score 1):

Any client should completely ignore comments, so they should not cause any problems. Anyway if the validator didn't complain it's probably ok.

Answer (score 1):

FYI if you're using AngularJS and create a `.directive` where `replace` is true, a comment outside the root element in the HTML fragment will cause Angular to see two root elements and throw this error

`Template for directive 'yourDirective' must have exactly one root element.`

Answer (score 0):

I had an SEO company that was working on a client's site decide to add an HTML comment into one of my PHP includes that was outside the HTML tag and it caused issues in Internet Explorer. It caused a bunch of formatting issues with my drop down menus. It made no sense why it broke, but it was absolutely 100% caused by the comment. As soon as the comment was deleted all went back to normal.

Comment: Unless you can present a demonstration, the description should be regarded as a false alarm; the problem was caused by something else (like an error in comment syntax, easy to make).

Comment: @Eric, Which version of IE was it?

Answer (score -1):

Yes by all means. Any rendering engine (IE, Firefix, Opera, Safari, etc) will ignore any HTML comment tag completely regardless which position.

Comment: This is not technically true as IE parses comments for conditional statements. See: "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Sounds like IE may not be a concern anymore.
> As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode